# C: State of memory during an array declaration

Tags: c, memory-management

I recently submitted a small program for an assignment that had the following two functions and a main method inside of it:

```
 /** 
  *  Counts the number of bits it
  *  takes to represent an integer a
  */
   int num_bits(int a)
   {
      int bitCount = 0;

      while(a > 0)
      {
         bitCount++;
         a = a >> 1; //shift to the right 1 bit
      }

      return bitCount;
    }

  /**
   * Converts an integer into binary representation
   * stored in an array
   */
   void int2bin_array(int a, int *b)
   {
      //stopping point in search for bits
      int upper_bound = num_bits(a);

      int i;
      for(i = 0; i < upper_bound; i++)
      {
         *(b+i) = (a >> i) & 1; //store the ith bit in b[i]
      }
   }

int main()
{
   int numBits = num_bits(exponent);
   int arr[numBits];     //<- QUESTION IS ABOUT THIS LINE 
   int2bin_array(exponent, arr);

   //do some operations on array arr
}
```

When my instructor returned the program he wrote a comment about the line I marked above saying that since the value of `numBits` isn't known until run-time, initializing an array to size `numBits` is a dangerous operation because the compiler won't know how much memory to allocate to array `arr`.

I was wondering if someone could:

1) Verify that this is a dangerous operation

2) Explain what is going on memory wise when I initialize an array like that, how does the compiler know what memory to allocate? Is there any way to determine how much memory was allocated?

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a C99 variable length array. It is allocated at runtime (not by the compiler) on the stack, and is basically equivalent to

```
 char *arr = alloca(num_bits);
```

In this case, since you can know the upper bound of the function, and it is relatively small, you'd be best off with

```
 char arr[sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT];
```

This array has a size known at compile time, will always fit everything you need, and works on platforms without C99 support.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I compile with gcc I am not setting `-std=c99` but this code is functioning fine the way it is, am I just lucky in this case because the upper_bound is so low?

Comment: gcc by default includes a bunch of non-standard C extensions. `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic` would not compile your code.

Answer (score 2):

It should be ok, it will just go on the stack.
The only danger is blowing out the stack.

malloc  would be the normal way, then you know if you have enough memory or not and can make informed decisions on what to do next.   But in many cases its ok to assume you can put not too big objects on the stack.

But strictly speaking, if you don't have enough space, this will fail badly.